# Flutter build: build failed

Tags: flutter, build

I am building apk of my flutter project but the error stated in the link below is occurring every time I try to build apk.

[Link to error](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39407)

I am providing this link because stack overflow is not allowing me to provide full stack trace.
Please help me so that i can publish my app

Answer (score 1):

I found that you are using `image_downloader-0.16.2` but recent version is `0.19.0` an changelog stated, that they `Fixed AndroidX migration`. Try to update `image_downloader` package, because lately there are a lot of errors related to `androidx`.